# How to set variables in URLSession data task?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, web-services, nsurlsession

I am trying to login with two text boxes (username and password). I am sending those two variables to web service to check whether there is username and password is available or not. I get the response as message "success" or "failure" from web service with respect to those two values. Then i am fetching that message and with that message i am setting a flag value. But after the session i am not getting that flag value. its showing the default value false.

The problem is i want to login on button action which will call web service using URLSession and data task and i am not able to set the flag. I can do it with NSURL synchronous request but that code is deprecated.

You can view images for the code for login button action function as well as web service function.
[login button action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUT4.png)
[web service function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8odr.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We're not going to click a link and look at images of code. Post your relevant code, marked with code tags, here. The problem is almost certainly that your login task is asynchronous, and the results won't be available until your completion handler or delegate method are called. Thus you'll need to restructure your code, but we can't tell you how to restructure your code until you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using the method `webServiceCalledMethod` is wrong. The task associated with the `URLSession` is executed asyncronously. As a result, `isLogin` variable is returned before your dataTask gets executed.

Instead of returning Bool from asyncronous method, use either closure or delegate pattern to notify of the data task completion state.

Comment: Yes exactly right. It is returning before task gets executed. I checked it. & yes it is asynchronous method. Thats why i was trying with synchronous method of NSURL but it is deprecated. Its giving suggestion that i should use URLSession. But i was not able to understand whether session is asynchronous or synchronous. Finally I used semaphores for waiting time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, don't use semaphores either. That will still block the main thread. You want to refactor your code to pass in a completion block that gets called once the async task is complete. You need to stop and read up on that concept until you understand it.

Comment: @DuncanC Could you please let me know if you have any other solution for this?